# Item color picker/swapper

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

Let's say I have two products: `iPhone 5 64GB (White)` and `iPhone 5 64GB (Black)`.

What's the best way to create a color picker/swapper if the names of the items include the color (which unfortunately cannot be changed)?

Ideally, the items should display once (as `iPhone 5 64GB`) and show a select box with options of `White` and `Black`.

In addition to the color being displayed in the item's name, there is also a color attribute in the database.

My initial thought was to have regex exclude everything inside the parentheses, then compare the names of the items to see if they match. If they do, grab each color from the database and  add the options to a select box.

However, I am not sure if this is the right approach so I'm seeking advice from the experts!

Comment: We know nothing about how your app is structured. Please show some code.

Comment: Can you create additional columns in the database?

Comment: @padde What would you like to see? And yes, I can create additional columns.

Comment: But you're not allowed or able to change existing records, right? The cleanest solution would be to update all existing records, removing the color from the title and keeping the color in a separate column which is already done. Is there really no way you can acheive that? Another solution would be to create an additional column with the cleaned up title and then group by that title.

Answer (score 0):

Ideally your database will contain data in a meaningful and structured way. If for some reason your data cannot be massaged into a clean schema, you're left to handle the data in your app (using regex or other methods as you suggest) in order to get it into the format that you need.

In the case presented here it sounds like you'll need to query your database to get the ipod entries and then filter / process these entries as necessary in your app.